# How can I use CalciteQueryEngine which uses mysql Lex?

Tags: ignite

I want to use CalciteQueryEngine which uses mysql Lex. But I don't know how to enhance it. I want to introduce a new config to control the SqlParser's Lex Config. What should I do?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greateful.

Comment: Is this an Ignite or a Calcite question? What new option do you want to add?

Comment: @StephenDarlington I want to introduce a config on this line https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/9a216817df1f9058c30dc90f3c62e16865b7032a/modules/calcite/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/query/calcite/CalciteQueryProcessor.java#L154

Comment: That would involve building your own version of Ignite. Maybe worth joining the user or developer mailing list to discuss (https://ignite.apache.org/our-community.html#contributing).